# How to capature the image in a Table in MVC3 (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have develop a MVC3 application in that i want capture the Image, that image i have set a table td baground. When i click the Button then i want capture that image .Is it possible in MVC3 ? If possible please help me .

Comment: What image do you mean?  What do you mean by "capture"?

Comment: hi, when i click on the button i want convert Perticuler td in to image and save that image.

Answer (score 2):

td's are html.  They are rendered by a browser, not the server.

Browsers do not have facilities to save the content they render as images.  The server doesn't know anything about how it's rendered.  It just sends text to the browser.

There is no way, short of an activex control of some sort (which won't work in FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc..) to render the iamge people see.

You could render an image on the server side.. but it would not, necessarily, be identical to what the end users sees because each browser reders html a little differently.  It would be hackish, and would require that you dig into the guts of the framework.  In any event, it would be a lot of work.  So, ask yourself, is months of coding really worth it for this feature?

Comment: Can we convert Entire viewpage into Image in mvc3..?

Comment: @Victor - I just gave you your answer, then you ask the same question again?  No, MVC does not provide a way to do that.  If you want to do it, you will have to write a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way convert My Mvc Viepage in to Image when click on button it needs to convert entire Mymvc view page to imge and save it .